# Accessing an stdClass Object

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

What is the best way of accessing this objects `tag_id`?

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [tag_id] => 100001 ) )`

Comment: That object doesn't have a `pet_id`, but if it did, `$yourarray[0]->pet_id`.  The outer structure is an array with one key `[0]`, which contains an object having the property `tag_id`, accessed via `->`

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have a pet_id? It's right there... and that's an actual result of print_r

Comment: @dcolumbus Maybe I am crazy, but I see exactly one property on the screen right now, and it is `tag_id`.

Comment: Ugh.. I'm sorry... I meant "tag_id" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo $var[0]->tag_id;
```